# Tomcat Ha conditional start of slave node

Tags: tomcat, high-availability

I am in a need of setting tomcat high availability but it's bit different than normal HA. I used a approach which is a combination of haproxy with hearbeat and it's running perfectly fine as desired.

Now my problem is I can't keep both of the tomcat instance running at the same time because once started the tomcat starts some runnable threads that keep communicating with specific network devices connected to the network, it then reads the data from network devices and store it into the database. If i keep both the tomcat running they will be running same workflow twice.

Any idea will be helpfule.

Thanks

Comment: if you're in control of the workflow, use some synchronized object in the DB (e.g. lock on a table row).

Comment: hmm, I am not sure about this. Is there any way where I can keep one instance of tomcat shutdown and start it only if master node goes down ?

Comment: no trivial way to do that. Frankly, master-slave when slave is actually down is considered old fashion... But do you _really_ need the whole Tomcat slave to be down? Isn't there some particular application that should alone actually be down?